# How do i apply a class structure to a csv and then sort it?

Tags: python, csv

I am pretty green to codeing in general and Python and I am trying to learn it on the fly so I apologize for any green mistakes ahead of time. My goal is to read a CSV file and sort the data. I figured that using a class would be best but I may be wrong. The format of the CSV file is as follows.

```
A,1,2,3  
B,3,2,1  
C,2,1,3  
D,2,3,1  
E,1,3,2  
F,3,1,2
```

Each line is a new item with the first letter being the name and the numbers being what I want the letter to be sorted by. The actual data will be a little different, such as the names will not simply be a letter, but the format will not change. I cannot figure out how to apply the class I made and sort it. Here is my code so far:

```
class art:
    def __init__(self, name, c1, c2, c3):
    self.name = name
    self.c1 = c1
    self.c2 = c2
    self.c3 = c3

    def __repr__(self):
    return repr((self.name, self.c1, self.c2, self.c3))

data = open('c:/tempdata/test_sort_data.csv', 'r')
f = data.read()
print f
```

I was planning on using the sorted function kind of like this:

```
sorted(f, key=lambda art: art.c1)
```

I am just using the `print f`  to check and make sure the data was read properly. When I finish I only want the sorted list to print. I eventually want to run a more complex sort using multiple parameters, all three numbers, but I cannot figure out how to sort it at all right now.I am not sure how to call it as I am not sure how to format my data to the class. I am also not adamant about using a class, it just seems like the cleanest way at the moment. Any assistance would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn each line into an `Art` instance (note upper-case convention for class names), you can do:

```
instances = []
with open('c:/tempdata/test_sort_data.csv') as data:
     for line in data:
         name, c1, c2, c3 = line.strip().split(",")
         c1, c2, c3 = map(int, (c1, c2, c3))
         instances.append(Art(name, c1, c2, c3))
```

In terms of sorting, you can implement the comparison "magic methods" in your class:

```
class Art:
    ...
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.c1 == other.c1
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.c1 < other.c1
```

Now you can just use `sorted(instances)`.

Comment: Thank you. I figured that I needed some sort of for loop but I could not figure out how to implement it. My ultimate goal is to have script run this multiple times, each time running on the next c# but ignoring the first object that was output for the previous c#. Example ignore 'A' as it was first output for c1 ... I think I can figure this out given all the information I have gained from the answers. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Using a class in that case would only make sense if you want to do something other than just hold data and sort the lines in the csv file. For example you could sort your data in a few lines without using a class:

```
import csv
with open("data.csv", "r") as csv_file:
  data = [line for line in csv.reader(csv_file)]
data.sort(key=lambda entry: entry[1])
```

But if you need a more complex way of sorting the entries then you could define a specific function to use in the `data.sort` method rather than use a `lambda` expression.

If you're not doing anything else than sorting with the data then I'd say you don't need to go through the "trouble" of defining a class.

A more elaborate version with command line arguments parsing would allow you to provide the path to the input file and specify the column to sort on - note that no error handling is done:

```
import argparse
import csv
import sys


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Build argument parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Sort data from the given file")
    parser.add_argument("--input", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--sort-column", required=True, type=int)
    # Parse command line arguments
    args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

    # Read data from provided file
    with open(args.input, "r") as csv_file:
        data = list(csv.reader(csv_file))

    # Sort data based on the provided 'sort_column'
    sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda item: item[args.sort_column])
    print "\n".join(str(item) for item in sorted_data)
```